# Implement a set of parameters in ssrs which are dependent on each other in any order

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence, azure-synapse

I have 4 columns in a table

```
Continent   Country     State        District
APJ         India       punjab       Tavi
APJ         India       punjab       xyz
APJ         India       punjab       abc
AMS         US          Washington   efg
AMS         US          Washington   yyy
AMS         US          Columbia     bbb
```

I need to create four parameters which are dependent on each other in any order.

when the report runs, following values should be selected in the parameters by default without any duplicates

```
parameter1 parameter2   parameter3   parameter4
APJ        India        Punjab       Tavi
AMS        US           Washington   xyz
                        Columbia     abc
                                     efg
                                     yyy
                                     bbb
```

**Requirement in SSRS with examples**

1. If I select only Punjab in parameter 3 then
   parameter1 should show only APJ , parameter2 should show only India and parameter4 should show only Tavi,xyz and abc.
2. If I select yyy and bbb in parameter 4 then
   parameter1 should show only AMS , parameter2 should show only US and parameter3 should show only Washington and Columbia
3. Similarly if I select a value in parameter2 then parameter1, parameter3 and parameter4 values should be dependent on parameter2
4. Similarly if I select a value in parameter1 then parameter2,parameter3 and parameter4 values should be dependent on parameter1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this easily, SSRS does not allow forward or circular dependencies. So if parameter 2 relied on parameter 1 then parameter 1 cannot rely on parameter two. Imagine the scenario with just two parameters, say country and province.

Dataset query for province might be `SELECT * FROM tblProvince WHERE Country = @pCountry`
Dataset query for country would be `SELECT * FROM tblCountry WHERE Province = @pProvince`

but `@pProvince` cannot be evaluated without running the associated query, which relies on `@pCountry` which cannot be evaluated without running the associated query which relies on `@pProvince` and round and round we go.

---

And now a possible answer... There may well be an easier way of doing this, however this should work...

In the following code `TestTable1` is the data you supplied in the question.

The basic idea is that we create a pair of datasets for each parameter, one which contains a list of available columns and the other a list of values from that column. I've only done two in this example but the principle is the same, each query will just have more parts to the `WHERE` clause.

The first dataset will be called 'dsP1Fields'. This is just a list of the 4 columns in our table so the following query will suffice (you could reference system objects to get the column names but it's overkill for this simple scenario)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(colName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('Continent'), ('Country'), ('State'), ('District')
SELECT * FROM @t
```

Now add a parameter called `p1Field` and set its available values to the `dsP1Fields` query.

We can test the report at this point to make sure we see the 4 items in the drop down... all good so move on...

Create a new dataset called `dsP1Values` and set its dataset query to be

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT ', @p1Field, ' as p1Values FROM dbo.TestTable1')

exec (@sql)
```

Note that we have to alias the returned column as SSRS always expects the same dataset structure to be returned, so whatever you choose will be called `p1Values`.

Now create a new parameter called `p1Value` and set its available value to the `dsP1Values` dataset.

If you test now, you'll see that the `p1Values` dynamically selects the correct values based on the field you chose.

OK, next up we do the 2nd parameter, this is very slightly harder as we have to accommodate choices made in parameter 1.

So, create a new dataset called `dsP2Fields` with the following query.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(colName varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('Continent'), ('Country'), ('State'), ('District')
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE colName NOT IN(@p1Field)
```

Note that we omit anything selected in the first parameter so you cannot choose the same column twice.

Now create a new parameter called `p2Field` and set available values to `dsP2Fields`.

Next, a new dataset called `dsP2Values` with the following query

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) 
    = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT [', @p2Field, '] as p2Values FROM dbo.TestTable1 ', 
             'WHERE ', @p1Field, ' = ''', @p1Value, '''')

exec (@sql)
```

Next a new parameter called `p2Value` with available values pointing to `dsP2Values`

If you test now you'll see that the selection is totally dynamic. You can continue with the other 2 parameters just remember to extend the query each time to accommodate the parameters that have already been set, just as I did for parameter 2.

Here's a short GIF to show this in action.

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make P1value as multi select and then use those multiple values in the retrieval query of Data-Set of p2Value

Comment: I've not tested this but you should be able change this...
 `'WHERE ', @p1Field, ' = ''', @p1Value, ''''` to this `'WHERE ', @p1Field, ' IN(', @p1Value, ')'` , but you might only be able to do this if you use numeric field values. I don't have me test machine around at the moment so I can't test this but if you put the modified expression in a textbox you can see what SQL is being generated and fix it up from there.

Comment: yes for numeric multi-select fields it will work but I am trying for text fields. I tried very hard. For text values, looks like single quoting is difficult. any thoughts or ideas?