# Change a parameter value in ssrs and use the same in the query of a dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

There is a parameter with multi select enabled.
The selected values are returned as comma separated.
For Ex.
The Parameter is `country` and is of text type.
The Values are `US` `UK` `IN` `DEN`.
If the user selects `US` and `UK`, the value `US,UK` is set as parameter value.
I want to use the selected values in the `IN` clause of a query. As the single quotes are required to check text values in an IN clause, the value has to be changed to `'US','UK'`.
I have written background sql code for the dataset as below

```
DECLARE @CountryValuesFormattedFinal NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @CountryValuesFormatted NVARCHAR(1000) = CONCAT('select replace(''',   @CountryValue,   ''','','','''''','''''')');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @CountryValuesFormatted, N'@frmtstr NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT', @frmtstr = @CountryValuesFormattedFinal OUTPUT;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) = CONCAT('SELECT continent FROM Countries WHERE country IN (''', @CountryValuesFormattedFinal, ''') group by continent');
exec (@sql);
```

But looks like the execute command is not working and not setting the output variable `@CountryValuesFormattedFinal` as the query is not returning any results.

**sql server version**

```
Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.17829.0 Aug 14 2022 18:54:26 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Do any of the results of searching for [`[tsql] variable where in`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+variable+where+in) point the way?

Comment: Are you doing this in the RDL? You can use =JOIN(Parameters!Country.Value,",") to bind the parameter in the dataset and use IN (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Country)) in the sql.

Comment: yes this is in RDL.

Comment: if you are using a query in your dataset (not a stroed proc) then you don't need any code to handle this. Just do something like `SELECT * FROM myTABLE where Country IN (@myCountryParameterFromSSRS)` . SSRS should automatically inject the correct string into the command for you. You don't need to handle the string parsing or anything using this method.

Comment: yes but I want to use a dynamic query which is executed by exec. This question is an extension to the comment in question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912655/implement-a-set-of-parameters-in-ssrs-which-are-dependent-on-each-other-in-any-o